# asp: select dropdownlist.SelectedItem as SQL WHERE condition

Tags: sql, asp.net

How to correctly set the sql statement in SqlDataSource ?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="customersDropDownList" runat="server" DataSourceID="customerSqlDataSource" DataTextField="KLIENT" DataValueField="KLIENT">
<asp:ListItem>Klient</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="projektSqlDataSource" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:pd1960ConnectionString %>" 

    SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT cast(PROJECT AS VARCHAR) + 
': ' + OPIS AS ProjektOPIS FROM [V_works] 
WHERE ([KLIENT]=" + customersDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text + ")">

    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Make sure you have set the property AutoPostBack  to true in your DropDownList.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the below

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="projektSqlDataSource" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:pd1960ConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT cast(PROJECT AS VARCHAR) + 
': ' + OPIS AS ProjektOPIS FROM [V_works] 
WHERE ([KLIENT]=@Customer">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="customersDropDownList" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
            Name="Customer" Type="String" DefaultValue="Klient" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And, make sure you set `AutoPostBack = "True"` in your drop down control